# How to search resources without a specific tag

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm using [AWS Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html) to query my cloud infrastructure through AWS API.

I can query resources by tag specifying a key=value pair in the filter, such as "Environment=Production". What I cannot find is how to query for null valued tags or non-existent tags. For example, I want to query for all EC2 instances that do not have a certain tag defined, let's say, all EC2 instances that do not have an "Environment" tag.

Is that possible with the SDK?

Comment: Not aware that you can do this with the SDK (other than doing client-side filtering) but the AWS console offers a similar feature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/scenario-finding-untagged.html)

Comment: thanks @jarmod but I need to use the sdk since I'm looking to automate tasks here.

Comment: Makes sense. Then I think your best bet is to describe all resources and apply a client-side filter. There are other proactive things you can potentially do here, for example write IAM policies that require instances to be tagged in a certain way, or write CloudTrail Log event handling that respond to instance launches without the requisite set of tags.

Comment: precisely, and as a first step I want to fix all missing tags automatically if possible. if no other way, will go with client-side filtering. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodejs child process in combination with the aws-cli eg:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec(`aws ec2 describe-instances --profile dev --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags]" --output text | grep None | awk '{print $1}'`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: thanks but I prefer a JS solution if possible. yours can be a workaround though!

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways to do that, is by using [describeInstances()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstances-property)

```
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({
    region: "us-west-2"
});
var clearThese = [];
ec2.describeInstances(function (err, data) {
    if (err) return err;

    data.Reservations.forEach(function (reservation) {
        reservation.Instances.forEach(function (instance) {
            //console.log(instance.Tags);
            let temp = instance.Tags.filter(function (arr) { return arr.Key === 'Environment' })[0];
            if (temp !== "undefined") {
                clearThese.push(instance.InstanceId);
            }

        });

    });
    console.log(clearThese);
});
```

So, you will have your **Instance IDs** in the `clearThese` array, which you can pass to [stopInstances()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#stopInstances-property) function to stop the VMs or [terminateInstances()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#terminateInstances-property) to directly terminate them.

Also, you can use a region array to run this code across all regions.